# how to add text in label tag simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using simple_form and trying to add text before the closing label tag.

```
<label>search</label>
```

This is what I have

```
<%= simple_form_for "", html: { id: "searchform1", class: "searchform", role: "search" }, :method => :get do |f| %>

<%= f.input "", wrapper: false, label_html: { id: "spanLabel0", class: "fLabel"}, input_html: {size: 27, name: "s", id: "s1", class: "s", title: "search"} %>

<%= f.submit "search", :type => :image, :src => "/assets/search.png", id: "searchsubmit1", class: "searchsubmit" %>

<% end %>
```

I'm looking to reproduce this (notice "search" before closing label tag):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" class="simple_form searchform" id="searchform1" method="get" role="search">

<label class="string required control-label fLabel" for="s1" id="spanLabel0">search</label>

<input class="string required s" id="s1" name="s" size="27" title="search" type="text">

<input class="searchsubmit" id="searchsubmit1" name="commit" src="/assets/search.png" type="image" value="search">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a label of Search for you form, simply put `<%= f.label :search %>:` before the `f.input` tag. You'll find more info on that in the [Action View form Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) documenttion